# WinSCP ExecuteCommand with stdin redirection?

Tags: c#, linux, stdin, winscp, winscp-net

Given:

```
var linuxCommmand = "/opt/ndmcli -x"; 
var linuxOptions = "sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;\nquit;"; 
SSH.ExecuteCommand(String.Format("{0} <<!!\r\n{1}\r\n!!\r\n", linuxCommand, linuxOptions));
```

Consulting the session log shows the command is correct, with this:

```
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 Script: call /opt/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmcli -x <<!!
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 quit;
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 !!
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 Executing user defined command.
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 /opt/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmcli -x <<!!
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 quit;
2016-10-25 14:12:49.433 !! ; echo "WinSCP: this is end-of-file:$?"
2016-10-25 14:13:04.437 Waiting for data timed out, asking user what to do.
2016-10-25 14:13:04.437 Asking user:
2016-10-25 14:13:04.437 **Host is not communicating for 15 seconds.
2016-10-25 14:13:04.437 
2016-10-25 14:13:04.437 Wait for another 15 seconds?** ()
```

Is there any reason I couldn't use stdin redirection with WinSCPNet's `ExecuteCommand`?

Thanks!

****UPDATE****
Weirdly, if I add a trailing space:

```
var linuxCommmand = "/opt/ndmcli -x"; 
var linuxOptions = "sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;\nquit;"; 
SSH.ExecuteCommand(String.Format("{0} <<!!\r\n{1}\r\n!!\r\n ", linuxCommand, linuxOptions));
```

It all works fine:

```
2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 Script: call /opt/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmcli -x <<!!

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;
2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 quit;

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 !!

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489  
2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 Executing user defined command.
2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 /opt/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmcli -x <<!!

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes;
2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 quit;

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489 !!

2016-10-25 15:58:03.489   ; echo "WinSCP: this is end-of-file:$?"
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550 Script: 
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550 Script:     **************************************************************
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550     **************************************************************
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550 Script:     *                                                            *
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550     *                                                            *
2016-10-25 15:58:03.550 Script:     *            Licensed Materials - Property of IBM            *
---- (log continues, and I get my expected output) ----
```

Comment: Confused...is there a question for an issue here?

Comment: Sorry, my question is at the beginning, I'll rearrange to make it more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: What is `ndmcli`? What does it do? What is `sel` command?

Comment: The edit makes even less sense

Comment: @Darren, is that better?

Comment: it's not the formatting, its the content. You ask if there is any reason you shouldn't do something but show it doing what you want. seems odd.

Comment: @Darren, my apologies!  No, the log is showing I want it to do what I'm asking, but the expected output is incorrect :)

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your problem, But I would not recommend anyone to use this technique. It's just a pure luck that it works.

Comment: @Martin, any idea why?  Is the WinSCP source code available for review?

Answer (score 0):

The new-lines will completely confuse WinSCP.

The command is actually not executed correctly, as the trailing `!!` has to be alone on a line, what it is not.

---

You have to put everything on a single line.

This can work:

```
( echo sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes; & echo quit; ) | /opt/cdunix/ndm/bin/ndmcli -x
```

Comment: The echo via pipe didn't work - which makes sense, lol.  ndmcli is a standalone executable that then expects the input of sel stat pnum=157 detail=yes; quit;, and then outputs the necessary information.

Comment: the command should have the final !! on its own line, as the \r\n is both before and after the final !!.   Does WinSCP do some sort of parsing of the command prior to sending it?

Comment: No it does not make sense, why it should not work? The `echo` produces the ouput that your command expects on input.

Comment: Not sure.  Reset back to what's in the original question, simply added a trailing space, and now it's working as expected.  Odd!